# JAVA Swing onclick opens a new window/JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtable, jdialog

Open new window/Jframe (i.e. in another class...Table_Edit) and i have another class of Image containing a single button. 
i want something like when i click that button that should popup a window Table_Edit one.
    package build;

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.ColumnSpec;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.RowSpec;
import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.FormFactory;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Table_Edit {
private JTextField textField;
private JTable table;

public Table_Edit()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setSize(600,400);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FormLayout(new ColumnSpec[] {
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            ColumnSpec.decode("default:grow"),
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            ColumnSpec.decode("default:grow"),},
        new RowSpec[] {
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            RowSpec.decode("default:grow"),
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            RowSpec.decode("default:grow"),}));

    JLabel lblTableName = new JLabel("Table Name :");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblTableName, "2, 2, right, default");

    textField = new JTextField(40);
    textField.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField, "4, 2, left, center");
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, "5, 4, 17, 1, fill, fill");

    table = new JTable();
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
  table.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null,, TitledBorder.CENTER,TitledBorder.TOP,null,          

  null));
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
        },
        new String[] {
            "Column Name", "Data Type", "NN", "PK"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] {
            String.class, Object.class, Boolean.class, Boolean.class
        };
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return columnTypes[columnIndex];
        }
    });
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(106);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(92);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(26);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(30);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, "22, 6, right, fill");

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Save");
    btnNewButton.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(33, 19));
btnNewButton.setIcon(newImageIcon(Table_Edit.class.getResource("/com/sun/java/swing/

plaf/windows/icons/TreeOpen.gif

 ")));
    panel.add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Exit");
btnNewButton_1.setIcon(newImageIcon(Table_Edit.class.getResource("/javax/swing/plaf/
metal/icons/ocean/close.gif")));
    panel.add(btnNewButton_1);
    frame.setVisible(true);    
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Table_Edit();
}
}
```

Comment: //This window should popup when i click a button in other window! //

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an `ActionListener` to the button.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    //This method will be called whenever you click the button.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new Table_Edit();
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, but can you tell what about old windows which open currently?