# How can we change the color of a rectangle on button click?

Tags: animation, button, jframe

My group and I are amateur programers and are currently working on a bingo program. We have created an entire bingo card set on a `Jframe`. We need to find a way to give a button to each rectangle so when it is clicked it changes its color. We are completely lost and currently do not have the knowledge to pursue our program further. All we have been able to do is create a bingo sheet.

```
Rectangle B1Box = new Rectangle (75, 85, 100, 100);
g3.draw(B1Box);

Rectangle B2Box = new Rectangle (75, 185, 100, 100);
g3.draw(B2Box);

Rectangle B3Box = new Rectangle (75, 285, 100, 100);
g3.draw(B3Box);

Rectangle B4Box = new Rectangle (75, 385, 100, 100);
g3.draw(B4Box);

Rectangle B5Box = new Rectangle (75, 485, 100, 100);
g3.draw(B5Box);

Rectangle I1Box = new Rectangle (175, 85, 100, 100);
g3.draw(I1Box);

Rectangle I2Box = new Rectangle (175, 185, 100, 100);
g3.draw(I2Box);

Rectangle I3Box = new Rectangle (175, 285, 100, 100);
g3.draw(I3Box);

Rectangle I4Box = new Rectangle (175, 385, 100, 100);
g3.draw(I4Box);

Rectangle I5Box = new Rectangle (175, 485, 100, 100);
g3.draw(I5Box);

Rectangle N1Box = new Rectangle (275, 85, 100, 100);
g3.draw(N1Box);

Rectangle N2Box = new Rectangle (275, 185, 100, 100);
g3.draw(N2Box);

Rectangle N3Box = new Rectangle (275, 285, 100, 100);
g3.draw(N3Box);

Rectangle N4Box = new Rectangle (275, 385, 100, 100);
g3.draw(N4Box);

Rectangle N5Box = new Rectangle (275, 485, 100, 100);
g3.draw(N5Box);

Rectangle G1Box = new Rectangle (375, 85, 100, 100);
g3.draw(G1Box);

Rectangle G2Box = new Rectangle (375, 185, 100, 100);
g3.draw(G2Box);

Rectangle G3Box = new Rectangle (375, 285, 100, 100);
g3.draw(G3Box);

Rectangle G4Box = new Rectangle (375, 385, 100, 100);
g3.draw(G4Box);

Rectangle G5Box = new Rectangle (375, 485, 100, 100);
g3.draw(G5Box);

Rectangle O1Box = new Rectangle (475, 85, 100, 100);
g3.draw(O1Box);

Rectangle O2Box = new Rectangle (475, 185, 100, 100);
g3.draw(O2Box);

Rectangle O3Box = new Rectangle (475, 285, 100, 100);
g3.draw(O3Box);

Rectangle O4Box= new Rectangle (475, 385, 100, 100);
g3.draw(O4Box);

Rectangle O5Box = new Rectangle (475, 485, 100, 100);
g3.draw(O5Box);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add an ActionListener to your Rectangles ? Try looking this :

[JAVA Swing onclick opens a new window/JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678829/java-swing-onclick-opens-a-new-window-jframe)