# How to open a specified window when the user clicks on a button

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Java and I'd like to event that open a window that I made with windowbuilder when the user click on the button called btnManga, there is the code in the principal.manga(themain window)

```
package biblio;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class principal extends JFrame{

    private JFrame frmAcceuil;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                    
                    principal window = new principal();
                    window.frmAcceuil.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    
    public principal() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmAcceuil = new JFrame();
        frmAcceuil.setBackground(new Color(40, 168, 253));
        frmAcceuil.setTitle("Acceuil");
        frmAcceuil.setResizable(false);
        frmAcceuil.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(66, 66, 66));
        frmAcceuil.setBounds(100, 100, 518, 571);
        frmAcceuil.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmAcceuil.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("BIBLIOTHEQUES");
        lblNewLabel.setForeground(new Color(40, 168, 253));
        lblNewLabel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic UI Semibold", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(134, 24, 226, 73);
        frmAcceuil.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Que voulez- vous acheter ?");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic UI Semibold", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblNewLabel_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNewLabel_1.setForeground(new Color(38, 217, 255));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(134, 84, 239, 28);
        frmAcceuil.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1_1 = new JLabel("OU");
        lblNewLabel_1_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNewLabel_1_1.setForeground(new Color(38, 217, 255));
        lblNewLabel_1_1.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic UI Semibold", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblNewLabel_1_1.setBounds(134, 328, 239, 28);
        frmAcceuil.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1_1);
        
        JButton btnManga = new JButton("MANGA");
        btnManga.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                manga mangaWindow = new manga();
                mangaWindow.setVisible(true);
              }
            });

        btnManga.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic UI Semibold", Font.BOLD, 20));
        btnManga.setIcon(null);
        btnManga.setForeground(new Color(66, 66, 66));
        btnManga.setBackground(new Color(40, 168, 253));
        btnManga.setBounds(122, 391, 261, 58);
        frmAcceuil.getContentPane().add(btnManga);
        
        JButton btnRoman = new JButton("ROMAN");
        btnRoman.setForeground(new Color(66, 66, 66));
        btnRoman.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic UI Semibold", Font.BOLD, 20));
        btnRoman.setBackground(new Color(40, 168, 253));
        btnRoman.setBounds(122, 234, 261, 58);
        frmAcceuil.getContentPane().add(btnRoman);
    }
}
```

Here the code in the manga.java that I'd like to display when the button btnManga is clicked

```
package biblio;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class manga extends JFrame {

    private JFrame frmAcheterDesLivres;
    private JTable mangatable;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    manga mangaWindow = new manga();
                    mangaWindow.frmAcheterDesLivres.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public manga() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmAcheterDesLivres = new JFrame();
        frmAcheterDesLivres.setTitle("Acheter des Livres");
        frmAcheterDesLivres.setResizable(false);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic Medium", Font.BOLD, 15));
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(66, 66, 66));;
        frmAcheterDesLivres.setBounds(100, 100, 758, 601);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_1_1 = new JButton("");
        btnNewButton_1_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(manga.class.getResource("/resources/mangas/blackClover.jpg")));
        btnNewButton_1_1.setBounds(31, 46, 125, 125);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1_1);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("");
        btnNewButton_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(manga.class.getResource("/resources/mangas/chainsawMan.png")));
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(225, 46, 125, 125);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_1_2 = new JButton("");
        btnNewButton_1_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(manga.class.getResource("/resources/mangas/BokuNoHeroAcademia.jpg")));
        btnNewButton_1_2.setBounds(414, 46, 125, 125);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1_2);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_1_3 = new JButton("");
        btnNewButton_1_3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(manga.class.getResource("/resources/mangas/jujutsuKaisen.jpg")));
        btnNewButton_1_3.setBounds(590, 46, 125, 125);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1_3);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Black Clover");
        lblNewLabel.setLabelFor(btnNewButton_1_1);
        lblNewLabel.setForeground(new Color(40, 168, 253));
        lblNewLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic Medium", Font.ITALIC, 14));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(31, 185, 125, 34);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JLabel lblMga = new JLabel("40 000 MGA");
        lblMga.setLabelFor(btnNewButton_1_1);
        lblMga.setForeground(new Color(40, 168, 253));
        lblMga.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        lblMga.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblMga.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic Medium", Font.ITALIC, 14));
        lblMga.setBounds(31, 210, 125, 34);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().add(lblMga);
        
        JLabel lblChainsawMan = new JLabel("Chainsaw Man");
        lblChainsawMan.setLabelFor(btnNewButton_1);
        lblChainsawMan.setForeground(new Color(40, 168, 253));
        lblChainsawMan.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        lblChainsawMan.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblChainsawMan.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic Medium", Font.ITALIC, 14));
        lblChainsawMan.setBounds(235, 181, 125, 34);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().add(lblChainsawMan);
        
        JLabel lblMga_1 = new JLabel("60 000 MGA");
        lblMga_1.setLabelFor(btnNewButton_1);
        lblMga_1.setForeground(new Color(40, 168, 253));
        lblMga_1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        lblMga_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblMga_1.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic Medium", Font.ITALIC, 14));
        lblMga_1.setBounds(225, 210, 125, 34);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().add(lblMga_1);
        
        JLabel lblBokuNoHero = new JLabel("Boku no Hero Academia");
        lblBokuNoHero.setLabelFor(btnNewButton_1_2);
        lblBokuNoHero.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        lblBokuNoHero.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblBokuNoHero.setForeground(new Color(40, 168, 253));
        lblBokuNoHero.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic Medium", Font.ITALIC, 14));
        lblBokuNoHero.setBounds(414, 181, 125, 34);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().add(lblBokuNoHero);
        
        JLabel lblMga_1_1 = new JLabel("35 000 MGA");
        lblMga_1_1.setLabelFor(btnNewButton_1_2);
        lblMga_1_1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        lblMga_1_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblMga_1_1.setForeground(new Color(40, 168, 253));
        lblMga_1_1.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic Medium", Font.ITALIC, 14));
        lblMga_1_1.setBounds(414, 213, 125, 34);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().add(lblMga_1_1);
        
        JLabel lblJujutsuKaisen = new JLabel("Jujutsu Kaisen");
        lblJujutsuKaisen.setLabelFor(btnNewButton_1_3);
        lblJujutsuKaisen.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        lblJujutsuKaisen.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblJujutsuKaisen.setForeground(new Color(40, 168, 253));
        lblJujutsuKaisen.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic Medium", Font.ITALIC, 14));
        lblJujutsuKaisen.setBounds(590, 181, 125, 34);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().add(lblJujutsuKaisen);
        
        JLabel lblMga_1_1_1 = new JLabel("23 000 MGA");
        lblMga_1_1_1.setLabelFor(btnNewButton_1_3);
        lblMga_1_1_1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        lblMga_1_1_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblMga_1_1_1.setForeground(new Color(40, 168, 253));
        lblMga_1_1_1.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic Medium", Font.ITALIC, 14));
        lblMga_1_1_1.setBounds(590, 213, 125, 34);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().add(lblMga_1_1_1);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Votre Panier de Mangas:");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic UI Semibold", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        lblNewLabel_1.setForeground(new Color(38, 217, 255));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(257, 291, 282, 34);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(61, 335, 641, 158);
        frmAcheterDesLivres.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        
        mangatable = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(mangatable);
        mangatable.setBackground(new Color(49, 49, 49));
        mangatable.setForeground(new Color(38, 217, 255));
    }
}
```

I've tried to do it myself

```
btnManga.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        manga mangaWindow = new manga();
        mangaWindow.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
```

However, this displays an empty window when I click on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA Swing onclick opens a new window/JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678829/java-swing-onclick-opens-a-new-window-jframe)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: 1) Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Don't use a null layout and don't use setBounds().  2) Class names SHOULD start with an upper case character. Learn and follow Java naming conventions. 3) An application should only have a single JFrame. A child window should be a JDialog 4) The real problem is that  your classes should NOT extend JFrame. You have two frames. The class itself and the JFrame created in the constructor. You are making the wrong frame visible.

Comment: so instead of creating a new JRame I should create a new Jdialog ?

Answer (score 0):

In your main method in `manga` you show the window correctly.

```
`mangaWindow.frmAcheterDesLivres.setVisible(true);`
```

In your action listener you call `mangaWindow.setVisible(true);` but `mangaWindow` has no components added to it. You need to includ the reference to the JFrame.

```
btnManga.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    manga mangaWindow = new manga();
    mangaWindow.frmAcheterDesLivres.setVisible(true);
  }
});
```

You should delete the `extends JFrame` to avoid this confusion. You should also use JDialog extra windows.

Comment: so I should use "extends JDialog" instead of "extends Jframe"?

Comment: No, you shouldn't extend anything because you're not using "manga" as a JFrame. You can declare `frmAcheterDesLivres` as a JDialog, but it isn't really relevant to your current problem. First fix the display part, then consider how you can change to use a JFrame and JDialog children.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using netbeans, create a button, then generate actionperformed on that button, then you can follow the following

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         manga mangaWindow = new manga();
         mangaWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: I'm actually oin eclipse and I've already added a actionperformed on the button and I've done everything well but idk why it doesn't wwork

Answer (score -2):

Did you try adding mangaWindow.[setSize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setSize(java.awt.Dimension)) before setVisible?

Edit: also you shouldn't have two different main methods in your application (technically there is nothing bad on it but it can be confusing because only one of them will be used when launching the application)

Comment: I didnt know having two different main method is bad thanks

Comment: no I didn't try it